# AlarmManager wont fire alarms android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have this alarm setting features in my app wherein users can set alarm on each activity on a goal. The feature worked at first few alarms that i set but after that, it wont fire alarms anymore. I don't know why. I think its something to do with AlarmManager. I cant find any sources in solving these problem.

This is my code:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MyDBAdapter dbhandler;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");

        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        //You can do the processing here.
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();


        //Release the lock
        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarms(Context context, int goal_id)
    {
        dbhandler = new MyDBAdapter(context);

        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        List<Activities> allActs = dbhandler.getAllActivitiesByGoal(goal_id);


        for (final Activities act : allActs) {

            //for alarm
            //Create an offset from the current time in which the alarm will go off.

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(act.getEDay()));  //1-31
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(act.getEMonth()) - 1);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(act.getEYear()));//year...

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, act.getHour());
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, act.getMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, act.getSecond());
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, act.getMillisecond());
            //MessageTo.message(SetNotifyActivity.this, hour+":"+minute+" "+format);

            //assigned a unique id to notifications


            //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ViewTasksActivity.class);
            intent3.putExtra("goalid", Integer.toString(goal_id));
            intent3.putExtra("activityId", Integer.toString(act.getActId()));
            intent3.putExtra("activityName", act.getActivityName());
            intent3.putExtra("show", "true");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    act.getActId(), intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    public void CancelAlarms(Context context, int goal_id)
    {
        dbhandler = new MyDBAdapter(context);

        List<Activities> allact = dbhandler.getAllActivitiesByGoal(goal_id);

        for (final Activities act : allact) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewTasksActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    act.getActId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            am.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help. :)